# Gitlab hooks - Changes removed from hooks after gitlab upgrade

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, upgrade, git-post-receive

I made changes in the `/hooks/post-receive` file and after upgrading gitlab I found that the changes were removed :/

How to keep my changes in future upgrades as they are important

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing your custom hooks in the `hooks` directory, put them in a new directory called `custom_hooks`. GitLab will execute any server-side hooks in this directory.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html gives more information. TL;DR, be sure the `custom_hooks` directory and the hook are owned by `git` and the hook should have the execute bit.